# React 'TypeError: items is not iterable'

Tags: reactjs, sorting, iterable, columnsorting, chakra-ui

I'm trying to implement this table-sorting solution into an application I am working on.  Here is the working codesandbox with the sorting feature I am trying to implement:
https://codesandbox.io/s/table-sorting-gxt7g?file=/src/App.js

However, when I try to implement this solution in my app, I get the error:

```
TypeError: items is not iterable
```

which points to the line containing `let sortableItems = [...items]`.
I get this error whether or not I initialize items as an empty array:
`const useSortableData = (items = [], config = null) => {` 
...or how I have it below.

I am trying to pass `myArrayOfObjects` to `useSortableData()`.

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

I should mention this is based on an example in this article: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/03/sortable-tables-react/

```js
  const useSortableData = (items, config = null) => {
    const [sortConfig, setSortConfig] = useState(config);

    const sortedItems = useMemo(() => {
      let sortableItems = [...items];
      if (sortConfig !== null) {
        sortableItems.sort((a, b) => {
          if (a[sortConfig.key] < b[sortConfig.key]) {
            return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? -1 : 1;
          }
          if (a[sortConfig.key] > b[sortConfig.key]) {
            return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? 1 : -1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
      }
      return sortableItems;
    }, [items, sortConfig]);

    const requestSort = (key) => {
      let direction = 'ascending';
      if (
        sortConfig &&
        sortConfig.key === key &&
        sortConfig.direction === 'ascending'
      ) {
        direction = 'descending';
      }
      setSortConfig({ key, direction });
    };

    return { items: sortedItems, requestSort, sortConfig };
  };

  const { items, requestSort, sortConfig } = useSortableData({ myArrayOfObjects });

  const getClassNamesFor = (id) => {
    if (!sortConfig) {
      return;
    }
    return sortConfig.key === id ? sortConfig.direction : undefined;
  };
```

Comment: you're passing an object instead of an array, try `useSortableData(myArrayOfObjects);`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Taki. That did it!

```js
 const useSortableData = (items, config = null) => {
    const [sortConfig, setSortConfig] = useState(config);

    const sortedItems = useMemo(() => {
      let sortableItems = [...items];
      if (sortConfig !== null) {
        sortableItems.sort((a, b) => {
          if (a[sortConfig.key] < b[sortConfig.key]) {
            return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? -1 : 1;
          }
          if (a[sortConfig.key] > b[sortConfig.key]) {
            return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? 1 : -1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
      }
      return sortableItems;
    }, [items, sortConfig]);

    const requestSort = (key) => {
      let direction = 'ascending';
      if (
        sortConfig &&
        sortConfig.key === key &&
        sortConfig.direction === 'ascending'
      ) {
        direction = 'descending';
      }
      setSortConfig({ key, direction });
    };

    return { items: sortedItems, requestSort, sortConfig };
  };

  const { items, requestSort, sortConfig } = useSortableData(myArrayOfObjects);

  const getClassNamesFor = (id) => {
    if (!sortConfig) {
      return;
    }
    return sortConfig.key === id ? sortConfig.direction : undefined;
  };
```